# in_groups_of giving undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue using `in_groups_of` and getting a `undefined method`each_with_index' for nil:NilClass` error.

I've used false as the second indicator in my `in_groups_of` call, but to no avail.

The code below is an outline of what I have. The method model loop will always have 3 records, so it works. But the progressions model loop can have 1 to 7 and this is where the issue is. Do I need to have a condition statement if [i] present? Or is there something I'm missing?

```
<% @data.each do |data| %>
  <% data.selections.size.times do |i| %>

    <% data.methods.order(:selection_id).order("date ASC").in_groups_of(3, false)[i].each_with_index do |e, index| %>
    ...
    <% end %>

    <% data.progressions.order(:selection_id).order("date ASC").in_groups_of(7, false)[i].each_with_index do |e, index| %>
    ...
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the below statement is not returning empty array

`data.progressions.order(:selection_id).order("date ASC").in_groups_of(7, false)`

Generally, if records are present then `in_groups_of` return `array of arrays` and if `collection(ActiveRecord::Collection)` is empty  then it returns just empty `array`

If it is returning an empty array it is preferred to check for `presence` of that array using `if` condition

```
<% if (collection = data.progressions.order(:selection_id).order("date ASC").in_groups_of(7, false)[i]).present? %>
  <% collection.each_with_index do |e, index| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Nimish. It does indeed return an empty array with your suggestion. Tp check for presence, you mean a conditional?

Comment: yes you can use `if` condition here
something like

`<% if (collection = data.progressions.order(:selection_id).order("date ASC").in_groups_of(7, false)).present? %>`

collection[i].each_with_index....

`<% end %>`

Comment: I have updated my comment accordingly. Hope this helps you out and solves your issue

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.